# Hebrew text not showing up properly

Tags: html, text, character-encoding, hebrew

well on my site for some reason any hebrew text is showing up like

```
 \u05d0\u05d9\u05d9\u05dc \u05d2\u05d5\u05dc\u05df
```

and so on, anyone know why? and how I can get it showing up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Hebrew text is supposed to be written by some software, possibly JavaScript code, where e.g. `\u05d0` within a string literal denotes the Unicode character U+05D0 HEBREW LETTER ALEF “א”. It sounds like such a construct has been mistakenly “escaped” e.g. so that the `\` character is preceded by another `\` character, which nullifies the meaning and turns the `\` to a mere character.

This was a rather abstract answer, though somewhat more concrete than the question. For a more detailed answer, please post some code.